# Get binary integer as input in python

Tags: python, binary-data

I am solving [Jumping on Clouds](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup) question, and **I know the algo for solving this problem**. `But my problem is with the syntax` I have just now started my journey with python and to be precise I am stuck on this.

**Requirement:** I need to make an array of binary integer, plus it should either be 1 or 0 only. For example: `[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]`

I have tried my level best to achieve this but no luck.

**MY Code:**

Now what I have done is, to get the binary number of the integer element, and then slice it off by 4 to get the last digit of the binary number. But it doesn't work with every every integer. Since I want the 0 or 1 from the binary number.

```
c = []
for i in range(0, 6):
  c[i] = int(bin(any_random_number)[4:])
```

I have also tried of doing this, `to check whether the input is 0 or 1, if not do not add it` but no luck

**Second Attempt:**

```
c = []
for i in range(0, 6):
  data = int(input())
  if(data == 0 or data == 1):
    c[i] = data
  else:
    data = 0
    c[i] = data
```

Any help would be appreciated. I just want to learn this, and take it to my work. Thanks :)

Comment: Notice that you can't access `c[i]` if there is no i'th element in `c`. Use `c.append(data)` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing it in a wrong way. c.append() works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a random array of 0s and 1s you can use the random module

```
[random.choice([1,0]) for _ in range(0,6) ]
```

This will output a random array of 0s and 1s

As your second attempt getting the user input you need to use the append method.

```
c = []
for i in range(0, 6):
  data = int(input())
  if(data == 0 or data == 1):
    c.append(data)
  else:
    c.append(0)
```

Comment: No I want to take the input from the user only.